# jQuery Fixed Header Table doesn't work with Angular2 ngFor

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular

I need to create table in Angular2  with fixed header and left (or right) column scrollable vertically and horizontally (both bars should be visibile all the time) and auto width columns. I've tried to do this without jQuery but eventually I had to use it. I found plugin [Fixed Header Table](http://www.fixedheadertable.com). However it doesn't work with ngFor- header doesn't scroll horizontally and left column is not fixed. Without ngFor it works correctly.

```
<table id="tableId>
       <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>col1</th>
            ...
       </tr>
       </thead>


         <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
               <th>{{item.arg1}}</th>
                  ...
               </tr>
         </tbody>
 </table>



...
export class itemComponent implements OnInit{

       ngOnInit(){
          $('#tableId').fixedHeaderTable({fixedColumn: true});
       }
}


<script src="node_modules/.../jquery.fixedheadertable.js"><script>
<script www.fixedheadertable.com/css/960.css rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script www.fixedheadertable.com/css/defaultTheme.css rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script www.fixedheadertable.com/css/myTheme.css rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Comment: what is this? <script www.fixedheadertable.com/css/960.css rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

Comment: Put `$('#tableId').fixedHeaderTable({fixedColumn: true});` after `ngFor items` loads successfully, instead of under `ngOnInit()` method

Comment: I found in some tutorial that it should be added to make fixedheadertable work properly

Comment: correct but your items are still blank when it triggers under `ngOnInit` method, you have to make it async, to initialize plugin after data loads successfully